# Coverting a FileField into binary then use lossless compression and decompress in django 1.11 + python3 + rest_framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following model below. How do I convert the **FileField** to binary and then use lossless method to compress,save it and later decompress it?

```
class EmployeeDocument(models.Model):
    """
    Model, Which holds Employee documents uploaded.

    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, related_name="employee_docs", null=True, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(
        upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')
    details = models.TextField()
    # url = models.URLField(null=True)
    # path_to_image = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    # upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'DOC - %s' % (self.employee.user.user
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that? Save disk space on the webserver?

Comment: Also note that JPEG images are usually already compressed with a combination of lossy and lossless algorithms, so further lossless compression might not save much more space or even increase space usage.